# Force call onStart, onStop fragment methods when dealing with transperent activity

Tags: android, fragment, transparent

I have two activities "A" and "B". 
"A" activity has a fragment. "B" activity is **transparent**.

When I push activity "B"  over activity "A"  fragment calls `onPause` (onStop isn't called). When I pop activtity "B"  the fragment calls only `onResume` (`onStart` isn't called).

It doesn't call `onStart` and `onStop`. I suspect it happens because activity "B" is transperent. Is there a way to **force calling** `onStart` and `onStop`?

I need to do some interface actions with fragment when activity "B" is popped. But I don't have any callbacks where I could do this actions. Because `onResume` is called when all activity views are already shown.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

just pass the reference of 'A' to 'B' and call the method of 'A' in 'B' directly.

Comment: I also suppose push activity "B" from other activities with same fragment so I don't want to do such reference in other activities.

Comment: depends on what the exactly condition to call your 'some interface actions'. a--register a broadcast in 'A' and send intent form onResume of 'B'. b--post a delay runnable to do the action in onPause of 'A'

Comment: 'Some interface actions' suppose layout internal fragment views in init state. I choose variant b. So when activity "B" is pushed I post a delay runnable as you mentioned above. But i can't say i like this way :)